# UITableView contentMode not working

Tags: ios, tableview, orientation-changes, contentmode

I have a `UITableView` and I set its `contentMode` to bottom. I expected when the orientation changes, the bottom part of the `UITableView` will stay foot and the top part will change.

Yet this doesn't happen.

I printed the content mode on the `willRotate` method and it seems fine.

Any ideas what could bother it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `contentMode` for `UITableView` does not work that way.

If you need the first cell on a bottom, you need to apply `M_PI` rotation affine  transform to your tableView and then rotate each cell back on `M_PI`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think contentMode is what you're after. That property usually only has an effect on more granular views, like a UIImageView.

It sounds like you're wanting to control how the view is scaled and stretched, I think what you're looking for is iOS's 'auto layout' feature. You can get started here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/